# Differences are between the following three ways of restriction of Google searching?

Tags: google-search

There are three similar ways of searching in Russian webpages:

- searching with `keyword site:*.ru`
- advanced searching by selecting Russia country as the region where webpages were published
- advanced searching by selecting Russian language

I wonder what differences and relations are  between them? I think the question boils down to differences and relation between domain, language and published region of webpages? What are they then?

Answer (score 3):

You already listed the differences - you're using "Russian" to mean three different things:

1. You can use your first method to search Russian TLDs. Anyone can purchase a TLD, in fact some television shows purchase websites ending in the TLD for the country of Tuvalu - "tv".
2. You can use your second method to search sites within the Russian country (i.e. Russia). I'm not exactly sure how they make this distinction, it may be from the IP address and you do find many of the results you would get in #1.
3. You can use your third method to search Russian language sites.

Comment: Thanks!What is the difference and relation between the first two?

Comment: @Tim #1 looks specific for sites with the .ru suffix, #2 uses IP or other means to tell where the site is 'based'.